# Qt5 widgets: twisted fonts on Zesty

Tags: qt, 17.04, qt5

I have a weird issue with fonts using Qt5 widgets on Ubuntu Zesty: some letters are randomly twisted, as shown in screenshot.

I have already tried installing fonts (`apt install fonts-*`) and turning off proprietary drivers with no luck. Also, same application runs fine on other systems.

Has anyone encountered such an issue?

Qt: 5.5, configured with: -opengl desktop -fontconfig -nomake examples -nomake tests -qt-xcb -qt-libpng -no-rpath -qt-xkbcommon-x11 -qt-pcre -no-icu

[image: screenshot]

Upd: fonts with size 48 or more are rendered properly

Comment: Why are you using Qt-5.5 while the repository has 5.7?

Comment: @Anwar project uses qtdeclarative module, Qt5.5 is the latest to support it

Comment: From which app you got that screenshot? How do I reproduce this? It looks like a graphics problem or a bug

Comment: @Anwar, It is from our project, and I cannot open sources. Can only say troubled elements are (mostly) `QWidgets`, placed into `QGraphicsScene` via `QGraphicsProxyWidget`

Comment: I think you may be incorrect on the QtDeclarative module. See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html#qtdeclarative-module-in-qt-5). If this is the case, I'd try with a later version to see if it fixes the issue. Otherwise, in situations like this you are best to try and produce a minimal test program you can share that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @gsxruk, well, as I mentioned above, `QtDeclarative` part has no troubles with fonts, but `QWidget/QGraphicsScene` has

Comment: The point is, test the application with the latest version (currently 5.9) to see if this may have been a bug that has already been fixed. You had stated above you couldn't do this because of the QtDeclarative module, which doesn't appear to be the case.